# For a given condition is it true that $a+b+c=3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose a, b, c  are positive real numbers such that

$$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\right)=16$$ 
Then is it true that  we must have  $a+b+c=3$ ?

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz $$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\geq\left(1\cdot1+\sqrt{a}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+\sqrt{b}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{c}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^2= 16$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=1$, which says that $a+b+c=3$.

Comment: Isn't the RHS of the inequality $(1\cdot 1+ \sqrt a \frac {1}{\sqrt a}+\sqrt b \frac {1}{\sqrt b} + \sqrt c \frac {1}{\sqrt c})^2$. I suppose we are taking dot product of the vectors $(1,\sqrt a,\sqrt b,\sqrt c)$ and $(1, \frac {1}{\sqrt a},\frac {1}{\sqrt b},\frac {1}{\sqrt c})$ on the RHS and squaring it. Please elaborate that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mathmore It was my mistake. I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Remember the inequality between the arithmetic and the harmonic mean
$$\frac{1+a+b+c}{4}\geq \frac{4}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+1}$$ for all $$a,b,c>0$$
the equality holds if $$a=b=c=1$$ thus $$a+b+c=3$$

Answer (score 1):

Expand your product to get $$4+\left(a+\frac 1a\right)+\left(b+\frac 1b\right)+\left(c+\frac 1c\right)+\left(\frac ab+\frac ba\right)+\left(\frac ac+\frac ca\right)+\left(\frac bc+\frac cb\right)=16$$

Now, the arithmetic-geometric inequality tells us that (for $x>0$): $$\left(x+\frac 1x\right)≥2$$ and that equality only holds when $x=1$.  This quickly implies that each of the variable terms in the expanded expression must be $2$ and that $a=b=c=1$ and we are done.